# Sending voicemail to email inbox

Tags: email, voip

Is there any software that makes it possible to send voicemail from a specific cell phone or Skype number to a specific email address? I'd like to be able to check my voicemail and email at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [Google Voice](http://voice.google.com)? You can configure it to send a speech-to-text email with a copy of the audio as an attachment to your email address.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the voicemail is being handled.  I don't use Skype much and don't know about its support for voicemail.   Some providers will allow you to configure your email to be forwarded to email.

I recently switched my landline to VoIP.  Among other features, voicemail can be forwarded to email.  Some providers allow forwarding incoming calls to multiple numbers.  You could port your cellphone number, and forward to a new cellphone number.

Google Voice provides good support for voicemail, but we found voice quality was not good in our area.  I had used it in the past and found it reliable, so it may have been a temporary issue.  Due to number portability availability, it wouldn't be our primary provider.  I have used it for outgoing calls, and don't have an incoming number with them.